# Image Flip Not Working In Safari

Tags: html, css

I'm currently checking browser support for my portfolio and noticed the  image flip isn't working in Safari. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

```
#effect-2 figure figcaption {
top: 15px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #226181;
text-align: center;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
transition: all 0.8s; 
}
```

Solution (add the webkit):

```
#effect-2 figure figcaption {
top: 15px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #226181;
text-align: center;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
transition: all 0.8s;
}
```

Comment: thanks i'll make the necessary adjustments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using all browser prefixes?

```
-webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
-moz-transform: rotateY(0);
-ms-transform: rotateY(0);
transform: rotateY(0);
```